# Why does the Android GC collect my native library References when the application is in Background?

Tags: android, linux, java-native-interface

I'm developing an Android application which uses a native library (.so).  I use `System.load` to load it and I add a JNI jar file to the classPath to make many references to an object created in my library.  The problem is, when my application is in background, Android removes all references to library object (all references are a static variable pointed to object in C++ lib), so the application crashes when resuming.

Can anyone help me please?

NB: I have an exception `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

Comment: The references aren't being garbage collected, rather what is happening is that your application's entire process is being reaped for resources.  On the restart, you are actually running in a brand new process which has never loaded the library.  If you are going to have anything which is process-level static, you'll have to make sure it gets re-loaded/re-initialized when needed on *every* possible path of entry into the app, not just your "front door" Activity.

Comment: thx Chris : i want to know what it is mean "rather what is happening is that your application's entire process is being reaped for resources", can you explain me more? That mean i should test if my library is loaded ? thank you again Chris

Comment: Your old program actually gets killed and then a new copy is run in a brand new process, but expected to pick up where the old one left off (if you log the process ID before and after you will see it has changed).  You don't actually have to check if the library is loaded, since attempting to re-load it when it's already loaded won't cause problems, but you can also set a flag when you've loaded it and check that.

Comment: that mean when application is resuming i re-load myLibrary and try to recreate all references ? How can i resolve this problem properly i have many references used in my application which refer object on the lib

Comment: You need to make your application able to be re-started in a new process from the onCreate() of any of its Activities, ie, you will have to be able to recreate everything, starting from any Activity.

Comment: so in OnCreate in earch library i must check if the references to my lib object are == null , if yes i must re-load my native lib and i must recreate all refernces , this process must be run in UI thread or i should use an another thread ? i should add some code in onCreate to do that ?

Comment: Rolled back 3rd party edit which had further confused the issues.

Comment: While I could imagine an argument for not loading the library from the UI thread, in practice people do seem to do it in onCreate() or elsewhere on the UI thread - unless something is badly wrong or you have extreme static constructors it should not be more involved than starting up the app itself.  Whatever references you hold based on the library you will have to figure out for yourself.  Anything that is process level static in the native library you will have to handle with a lot of care, paying careful attention to the lack of any 1:1 correspondence between an Activity and a process.

Comment: thc Chris problem resolved i detect when OS re-load my Application and i load my lib it's works fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The garbage collector does not.  Rather you are experiencing cases where the application is being resumed in an entirely new process which has not yet loaded the native library.